# In Notion, how to calculate Sum and Average in a rollup cell (missing option) - not a rollup column?

Tags: formula, rollup, notion

A rollup field, "Sprint Rollup" contains an n number of numbers, a rollup of a formula field from a Sprint db, as we can't do a rollup of a rollup.

I would like a formula to calculate the average of these numbers.

[image]

I recognize that I need to get the sum and number of numbers in the set, but I'm stuck on this.

I've seen other rollup-related examples, [like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBBN0.png), but it's not what I'm looking for.

I have tried `.toNumber()` which only returns the first number in the set.  `.format()` doesn't work either and I still the the count.

Assistance will be appreciated, thank you.

-- UPDATE --

From the Sprints table:

[image]

[image]

Essentially here is the issue:  Rollup columns contain a calculation option at the bottom, i.e. Sum, Average.  These two options are notably missing from a rollup cell that contains an array of values.  That's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a formula column to your db with the following input

```
toNumber(prop("Sprint Rollup"))
```

Then you can calculate the sum of the formula column you created, you can also hide the rollup column to avoid redundancy.

Comment: Thank you, but that only returns the first number in the set.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried turning progress # into a number like this: toNumber(whatisinthe progress # formula) It needs to be a number before it is rolled up to the other database. By the looks of the alignment to the left it looks like it's not a number yet.

Comment: That's the suggestion below.  Basically, what I would like to see is all the calculate options offered at the bottom of a rollup column to be available in rollup cells (avg, sum...)
Working with Notion on this issue as well.

Comment: To get a better picture can you show us the expanded view of the "progress" rollup and what is in the cells that this rollup is from? And also the formula in the progress #